How to get DigitalOcean to deploy from GitHub with pnpm
I am attempting to install a Node API. The API is running on a DigitalOcean droplet Ubuntu 24.04. The connection to GitHub was set up using the standard app.
I am using apps to deploy from GitHub on change push from a local MacBook.
My application is dockerised, and there are no issues with "docker compose up" on the local MacBook.
I get the error message:
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ INFO[0003] RUN pnpm install                             
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ INFO[0003] Cmd: /bin/sh                                 
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ INFO[0003] Args: [-c pnpm install]                      
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ INFO[0003] Running: [/bin/sh -c pnpm install]           
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ /bin/sh: pnpm: not found
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 127
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ 
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ command exited with code 127
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │ 
[2024-05-19 19:16:58] │  ✘ build failed

Here is my package.json
...
"scripts": {
"preinstall": "npm install -g pnpm",
"prebuild": "rimraf dist",
"build": "pnpm install && pnpm run && nest build",
...
}
"engines": {
"node": "20.9.0",
"pnpm": "9.1.1"
}

